# SQL query access pivot - error message 'field that has an invalid data type'

Tags: ms-access, pivot-table, linked-tables

I'm running an SQL Query on MS Access.

the query looks like this:

```
TRANSFORM MIN(X_VALUE*MULTIPLE & ' ' & Y_VALUE)
SELECT A.ID
FROM ((MY_TABLE_A A
       INNER JOIN MY_TABLE_B B ON B.ID = A.ID)
      INNER JOIN MY_TABLE_C C ON C.FOO1_ID = A.FOO1_ID)
LEFT JOIN MY_TABLE_D D ON A.FOO2_ID = D.FOO2_ID
```

<del>WHERE A.NUM ='FOO' 
AND A.FOO_ID<>0
AND FOO3=1</del>

```
GROUP BY A.ID PIVOT X_NAME IN('BLAH1', 'BLAH2')
```

when running this against local MDB file, it works.
when running this against Linked MDB (tables are linked to remote Oracle DB), I'm getting

> ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] The Microsoft
>   Access database engine could not execute the SQL statement because it
>   contains a field that has an invalid data type.

I've googled it, and couldn't find anything useful.

Any idea what can I do?
thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the Connection string you are using to execute this Query?

Comment: the connection string is the same one for both MDBs - I simply switch between the files (linked and unlinked). do you think it's relevant?

Comment: Comparing the data types of the linked table to the local one may offer some clues. What is the data type of A.NUM?

Comment: @rontornambe - thank you!. but I've tried to remove all WHERE conditions, and it gave the same error.

Comment: Let me know data type in Oracle for these 3 fields and as well in MS Access X_VALUE, MULTIPLE, Y_VALUE . The implicit data type conversion or data itself may not be same for MS Access table and Oracle tables.

Can you run following query for linked tables, if there is any problem with join's field data type, we will understand

     SELECT A.ID FROM ((MY_TABLE_A A  INNER JOIN MY_TABLE_B B ON  
     B.ID = A.ID)    INNER JOIN MY_TABLE_C C ON C.FOO1_ID =A.FOO1_ID)
     LEFT JOIN MY_TABLE_D D ON A.FOO2_ID = D.FOO2_ID 
     GROUP BY A.ID PIVOT X_NAME IN('BLAH1', 'BLAH2')

Comment: @ShamYemul types in MS Access are:
Non-linked:
`MY_TABLE_B.X_VALUE` is `Number`
`MY_TABLE_B.Y_VALUE` is `Text`
`MY_TABLE_D.MULTIPLE` is `Number`

Linked:
`MY_TABLE_B.X_VALUE` is `Number`
`MY_TABLE_B.Y_VALUE` is `Memo`
`MY_TABLE_D.MULTIPLE` is `Number`. so, the only difference is between Text and Memo

Comment: @itsho looking to your comments below, the Transform is working but too slow. It might be slow because of iif to handle Null values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only statement in the query that even vaguely seems it would cause data type issues is the mixed types in the transform statement. Perhaps the following would work:

```
TRANSFORM MIN(CSTR(X_VALUE*MULTIPLE) & ' ' & CSTR(Y_VALUE))
```

Comment: Thanks. I've tested on both linked and non-linked. both gave same error - `Invalid use of Null` without any other information. but I guess that this is the correct direction

Comment: there was a difference between Y_VALUE column type in between and non-linked. (Memo Vs Text).   I've ended up with `CSTR(IIF(Y_VALUE IS NULL, '', Y_VALUE))`. it works, but extremely slow.

Comment: Unfortunately, ODBC is forcing all data to be transferred to the local machine because IIf is not a standard SQL function, so the entire query must be processed by Access. To solve the performance issue you will need to convert the query to an Oracle pivot query and call it using the Access pass-through query mechanism.

Comment: thank you. can you provide a short example how to run query on Oracle server?

Comment: If you Google "ms access create pass through query" and/or "ms access vba run pass through query" you will find lots of examples on how to do this.

Comment: obviously :-). I've found [that](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/process-sql-on-a-database-server-by-using-a-pass-through-query-HA010206488.aspx). thanks!